# i made a class to create a HashMap and am not being able to implement it form another class in the same package in java

Tags: java

```
    package BIB;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Mapping_File{

             static Map<String, String> words = new HashMap<>();

             public static void main(String[] args){

                     words.put("WCRE", "Working Conference on Reverse Engineering (WCRE");
                     words.put("ICSE", "International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE)");
                     words.put("IWSC", "International Workshop on Software Clones (IWSC)");
                     words.put("ASE", "Automated Software Engineering (ASE)");
                     words.put("ACSAC", "Annual Computer Security Applications Conference (ACSAC)");


             }// end of main method

            public Map  <String, String> getWordsMap(){

                    return words;

            }// end of the get method
    }// end of the class
```

This is my class that contains the hash map, which, i believe, works perfectly fine. Now i have another class that is supposed to access value from this mapping file.
        package BIB;

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;

    public class FileParser{

            Mapping_File mf = new Mapping_File();

            public static void main(String[] args){

                    String Readline = "WCRE";
                    String converted = null;
                    Map<String, String> word = mf.getWordsMap();

                    if(word.containsKey(Readline)){

                            converted = word.get(Readline); 

                    }// end of the if

                     else if(word.isEmpty()){

                             converted = "the map you are looking for is empty.";


                     }// end of else if

                     else{

                             converted = "Could not find the elaborated form"; 

                     }// end of else

            System.out.println(converted);

            }// end of the main method


    }// end of the class FileParser
```

What i keep on getting is "the map you are looking for is empty." Am i doing any mistake while trying to access the mapping file ?

Comment: That shouldn't compile. Does it?

Comment: You've got two different spellings of MappingFile and Mapping_File, you're using a non-static field within a static method.... again does this compile?

Comment: Only one `main` method will execute -- whichever one you specify when you start Java.  If you are launching with `FileParser.main`, then `MappingFile.main` is not being executed.  Perhaps you want a static class initializer in `MappingFile` instead of a second `main` method?

Comment: The file does have same spelling. Sorry, i typed it wrong here. So it does compile and run.

Comment: I am launching with FileParser.main. So,How do i use an static class initializer in MappingFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your code error, there's syntax error when i try to recompile it (rename MappingFile to Mapping_File).
2. Instead to declare on main, declare your map in **constructor**.

change your mapping class become below code :

public class Mapping_File{

```
     static Map<String, String> words = new HashMap<>();

     public Mapping_File(){

             words.put("WCRE", "Working Conference on Reverse Engineering (WCRE");
             words.put("ICSE", "International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE)");
             words.put("IWSC", "International Workshop on Software Clones (IWSC)");
             words.put("ASE", "Automated Software Engineering (ASE)");
             words.put("ACSAC", "Annual Computer Security Applications Conference (ACSAC)");


     }// end of main method

    public Map  <String, String> getWordsMap(){

            return words;

    }// end of the get method
 }// end of the class
```

Comment: declaring my map on the constructor helped thank you so much